# Related Entries broken after upgrade to 2.6

Tags: upgrade, related-entries

I just upgraded to 2.6 and everything seemed to go ok until i found a piece of the template code on the site.

```
{related_entries id="task_lead"}{/related_entries}
```

Now when i go to the template code it shows:

```
{related_entries id="task_lead"}{staff_name}{/related_entries}
```

notice the {staff_name} variable, which i think is kind of weird

Comment: found the Ellis lab blog article http://ellislab.com/blog/entry/relationships-evolved-for-expressionengine-2.6 guess there is a new tag system. the system should do the converting of tags.... not sure what to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem and had to convert the {related_entries} tag to the new relationships format:

From:

```
{related_entries id="task_lead"}{/related_entries}
```

To:

```
{task_lead}{task_lead:title}{/task_lead}
```

Or for a URL:

```
{task_lead}<a href="url/{task_lead:url_title}">{task_lead:title}</a>{/task_lead}
```

Ellis labs claim that the templates will be automatically updated to the new format, but this didn't work for us.

Answer (score 0):

EE has released 2.6.1 which resolves this bug.

Comment: Did this manually